# Create a dynamic div content based on data from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a array object with some set of data in my js side.And in my html I need to dynamically create a div with set of this data on button click.

Below is my actual html

```
 <div class="grid-container">
    <h4 class="secondary bot-space-md">Certificate</h4>
        <a href="#" class="primary closeIcon icon-Delete"></a>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6">
                 <label>Country</label>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                 <label>Certificate Name</label>
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6">
                 <label>Certification Board</label>
                 <p>test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                 <label>Issue Date</label>
                 <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="text-primary label-2 secondary viewCertificate">View Certifacte</a>    
        </div>
```

In the above html the div class="row" is repeating with different label name and value.

Now when my function is called I'm trying to automatically form this html by iterating the loop

```
function saveDegreeData() {
   var [{name: "Country", value: "test"},{name: "Certification Name", value: "test"},
{name: "Certification Board", value: "test"},{name: "Issue Date", value: "test"}];
//Using this above data how can we create above html with in js so that I can append to my existing html
}
```

Can someone help

Comment: What you've tried so far ?

Comment: @SagarJajoriya I tried using for loop..But could escape characters

var degreediv = "";
    for(var i=0;i<degreedata.length;i++){
degreediv += "<div class="row"><div class="col-6"> <label>degreedata[i].name</label> <p>Test Data</p> </div> <div class="col-6"> <label>degreedata[i].value</label> <p>Test Data</p> </div> </div>";
}
console.log(degreediv);